# Editing HTML of a page in Weebly

Tags: weebly

I have a page with:

- title
- image gallery

with code for title:

```
<h2 class="wsite-content-title" style="text-align:left;"><font color="#515151" size="5">​&nbsp; External / Internal</font></h2>
```

and the code for image gallery.

I want to make a wrapper div for these both elements (title and image gallery, which are h2 and a div)  with HTML. Is there a way to do that?

I found the code using Inspect in Chrome... but to change the code, I need to know where it is in the Weebly editor. I can't find it.

Note: the page is a "Standard Page" (as opposed to "Blog Page")

Comment: Which template are you using? Where have you tried looking so far?

Comment: This post would be better suited to Weebly's help centre rather than here ,

Comment: Does the template make a difference? I understand that the code has to be somewhere under "edit CSS/HTML", but can't find the specific page (where HTML pages naturally go)

Comment: I asked at Weebly forums, but obviously it take so much time to be answered ... if they answer anyway.